# How to get the characters from a byte array encoded in python

Tags: python

i have a byte array encoded in utf-8 format. i need to get the characters from it and write into a file. please help
say b is a byte array

```
b=[1,1,-127,-125]
```

I need to convert each byte into a character

Comment: What is the character range? -127 isn't a valid ASCII value... E.g. the ASCII value for `a` is 97, and you can convert this like so: `ord('a')`, or vice versa: `chr(97)`. But the values you posted doesn't map to any (readable) characters, so I guess something else is going on.

Comment: am sry i wanted to suggest some negative values . -127 is not a valid value sry for providing incorret values.

Comment: Perhaps update your question then to use realistic values. Take a look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) for the valid values the `chr` function can handle.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2: You can use the `chr()` function. One more hint: It doesn't matter what encoding the list of integers has.

Python 3: You can create an instance of `bytes()` from the list.

Comment: @RaghuDev No, `ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)`

Comment: I considered answering that the OP can say what she or he pleases to. I decided not to answer this question at all because it shows zero effort on their side. *shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> def func(x):
...    if x < 0:
...        x += 256
...    return unichr(x)

>>> map(func, b)
[u'\x01', u'\x01', u'\x8a', u'\x8c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
b = [1,1,-127,-125]
for c in map(lambda x: x if x >= 0 else 256+x, b):
    print chr(c)
```